# renewing an access token in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, access-token

This is my first question, please bear with me. I am working with an API that authenticates using an access token that expires in 15 minutes, there is no refresh token to use in-lieu of a re-login. So far I have been able to get the access token and insert it into the `requests.get` call but I cannot seem to get it to renew and am at a loss as to how.
All of the work done with this API, and in general, is with Python so I am hoping to keep it in Python throughout and in the same file.

I get a `401` message code once the 15 minutes are up, and code `200` if successful. So far my only ideas are to put it on a timer for renewal but I cannot make heads or tails of stackoverflow posts or the documentation on doing that, have the login running in a separate script and then this script calls the other one for the current header variable (but that still would require a timer), or have it call to redo the login function once it hits a `response.status_code != 200`.

**Example script for getting the access token**

```
import requests, os, json, time, csv
def login (url, payload):
    #this will log into API and get an access token
    auth = requests.post(url, data=payload).json()
    sessionToken = auth["token"]
    sessionTimer = auth["validFor"]
    headers = {'Access-Token': sessionToken}
    return headers
#calling the function to generate the token
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "url inserted here"
    u = input("Enter your username: ")
    p = input("Enter your password: ")
    t = input("Enter your tenancy name: ")
    payload = {'username': u, 'password': p, 'tenant': t}
    print("Logging in")
    headers = login(url, payload)
#the actual work as pulled from a csv file
valuables = input("CSV file with filepath: ")
file = open(valuables, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
csvin = csv.reader(file)
for row in csvin:
    try:
        uuidUrl = row[0]
        output_file = row[1]
        response = requests.get(uuidUrl, headers=headers)
        print(response.status_code)
        with open(output_file, 'wb') as fd:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                fd.write(chunk)
        fd.close()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print(output_file,"may have failed")
        login(url, payload)
        continue
```

I couldn't get it to successfully recognize a `if response.status_code != 200:` as a way to call back on the login(). I also couldn't seem to get it to exit a `while True:` loop.

I apologize I cannot give more details on accessing the API for other people to try out. It is non-public

Comment: I notice you call `login()` at the bottom, but don't assign the result anywhere. You need to reassign `headers = login(url, payload)`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I added <code>headers = login(url, payload)</code> before calling the csv file and then within the loop trying to call the headers again. Without success, like so:

    <code>headers = login(url, payload)
    csvin = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csvin:
 try:
  uuidUrl = row[0]
  xip_file = row[1]
  response = requests.get(uuidUrl, headers=headers)
  status = response.status_code
  if status == "401":
   login(url, payload)
   headers = login(url, payload)
   response = requests.get(uuidUrl, headers=headers)</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I was able to figure out the answer to my own question. Posting this for later users. Updated snippet is below.

Short version of the story: requests.status_code was sending back a integer but I made the faulty assumption that it would be a string, thus my internal comparison was no good.

```
for row in csvin:
    try:
        uuidUrl = row[0]
        xip_file = row[1]
        response = requests.get(uuidUrl, headers=headers)
        status = response.status_code
        print(status)
        if status == 401:
            print(xip_file, "may have failed, loggin back in")
            login(url, payload)
            headers = login(url, payload)
            response = requests.get(uuidUrl, headers=headers)
            with open(xip_file, 'wb') as fd:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                    fd.write(chunk)
            fd.close()
        else:
            with open(xip_file, 'wb') as fd:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                    fd.write(chunk)
            fd.close()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print(xip_file,"may have failed")
        headers = login(url, payload)
        continue
```